# Conjugates of a cyclic subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group, $x\in G$ and let the cyclic subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ is not normal in $G$. 
Let $z\in G$, $|z|=p$ and $\{\langle xz^i\rangle~|~1\leq i\leq p-1\}\cap [\langle x\rangle]_G\neq \emptyset$ .
Is it true that $\{\langle xz^i\rangle~|~1\leq i\leq p-1\}\subseteq [\langle x\rangle]_G$? 
 (Note that $p$ is  prime, $|z|$ denotes the order of the element $z$  and $[\langle x\rangle]_G$ 
 denotes the conjugacy class of the cyclic subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ in $G$)

Thank you very much for your contribution!

Comment: Do you mean $ \{\langle xz^i\rangle~|~1\leq i\leq p-1\}\cap [\langle x\rangle]_G\neq \{ 1 \}$? The intersection will never be empty as it contains the identity.

Comment: @Bysshed, these two sets of subgroups do not contain trivial  subgroup of the group, so my mean from their nonempty intersection is a cyclic subgroup which belong to both sets.

Comment: But every subgroup contains the identity, so their intersection will contain the identity too.

Comment: Under your hypotheses, a counter example would be $z =f$ and $x=rf$. Where we are working in the symmetry group of the square, and $r$ is a quarter rotation and $f$ a reflection.

Comment: @Bysshed, I mean by $[\langle x\rangle]_G$  the set $[\langle x\rangle]_G=\{\langle x\rangle^g\ |\ g\in G\}$ so this is NOT a subgroup and it is just a set.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

Consider the symmetry group of the square, $D_8$. Let $r$ be a quarter rotation, and $f$ be a reflection. In keeping with your notation, let $x = r^2 f$ and $ z =f$. We have that $\langle x \rangle = \{e ,r^2 f \}$ and $\langle z \rangle = \{e ,f \}$. Moreover $\{\langle xz^i\rangle \mid 1\leq i < 2-1\} = \langle xz \rangle = \langle r^2 \rangle$.

Since $r^2$ is in the centre of $D_8$, $r^2$ is conjugate to itslef only. In particular, $r^2$ is not conjugate to $x= r^2  f$.